# Using ipython notebook offline

Tags: ipython, offline

Can ipython notebook be used when not connected to the internet?
My installation doesn't open a web browser tab if not online.
Thanks!

Comment: works for me: Mac OS X 10.8, with python installed from the Anaconda distribution http://www.continuum.io/downloads What is the error message, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it should work without needing an internet connection. If a browser tab doesn't open automatically, open a browser and go to the URL it gives you in the terminal where you started the notebook (by default, this is `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` ). It uses the 'loopback' network interface, which stays within your own computer.

Comment: I don't get there. If offline, the notebook doesn't start, there's error messages, the last one being:

 gaierror: [Errno -9] Address family for hostname not supported


and then the program returns to shell input, ipython doesn't run.

Comment: What version are you using? I can get that error with 0.13.2, but it works properly with 1.1.0.