# Do I need internet to use jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am a beginner in the jupyter world. There are many occasions where I do not have access to internet, in such cases sometimes I get errors in jupyter... For example I was trying an import:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

And I got this error:

[image]

Then, I connected to internet and the error did not appear.

I have my jupyter locally and it works without internet most of the time, but every now and then I get errors like that.

Problem is that internet is scarse and maybe I have to wait days until I can connect to the internet. Do I need internet to use jupyter notebooks or what am I missing?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704175/using-ipython-notebook-offline

Comment: No, you don't. And that error is quite strange, I would be very surprised if it had any relation to you being connected to the internet. Can you post the *full error message*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ipython notebook offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704175/using-ipython-notebook-offline)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jupyter notebook runs on a local server on your computer, so there is no need of internet connection.

The error you're reporting seems not related to a connectivity issue, but possibly related to `numpy`.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I think the same. But, if I have it locally and I have imported it before, why it does that? it is as if it goes to the source to check if it has the last version? My goal is to be able to work 100% offline, preventing all of this checks if possible...

Comment: Check the version of `numpy` you're using, you may need to upgrade it. It seems this is a known issue on some versions (https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3655)

Answer (score 0):

You can install local anaconda framework. Use this for your local development, in a way you will not need internet connection for development.

for Windows:
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/

---

for Mac:
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/

---

for Linux:
https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/01-Orientation/01.05-Installing-Anaconda-on-Linux/

---